# Как сложить разные единицы в css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Не получается сложить  vh к px.Вопрос такой: Можно ли реализовать такой эффект на js и как?

```css
.first{
  height:70vh + 64px;
  background:#000;
  width:50%;
}
.second{
  height:70vh;
  background:red;
  width:50%;
}
.header{
  height:64px;
  background:green;
}

/* ROW */
.row{
  display:flex;
  height:2000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="first"></div>

  <div class="second">
    <div class="header">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте calc().
Пример использования:

```css
.first {
  height: calc(70vh + 64px);
  background: #000;
  width: 50%;
}

.second {
  height: 70vh;
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
}

.header {
  height: 64px;
  background: green;
}


/* ROW */
.row {
  display: flex;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="first"></div>

  <div class="second">
    <div class="header">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

ps: Почитать можно [здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/css/calc).